# android: Dynamically load data into ExpandableListView does not work, maybe because of clearing the data List for ListChild element

Tags: java, android, algorithm, arraylist, expandablelistview

I have a ExpandableListView and I want to insert a String in the Child of the ListView. The format is for example: "01:22:56;1".The Number behind the semicolon indicates under which header the String Value before the semicolon should be put. I wrote an algorithm that should achieve this, I have tested it in Eclipse and it is working there.

However when I use this algorithm in my android app all headers are empty. I assume this is because I clear the ArrayList liste2 after putting it as data for hte header. But I need to clear the list, because otherwise my algorithm would not work. How can I improve my algorithm, so that I do not have to clear liste2?

```
for(int g=0;g<listDataHeader.size();g++){
        for(int k= 0; k<liste1.size();k++){
            if(liste1.get(k).contains(";"+g)){
                liste2.add(liste1.get(k).substring(0, liste1.get(k).indexOf(";")));
            }
        }
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(g),liste2);
        liste2.clear();
    }
```

Comment: create a deep clone of `liste2` and put that into `listDataChild`.

Comment: Can you explain how I should do this, I looked it up, but I do not really know how I should use that here, because from what I understood I would need an undefined number of clones, equal to the number of headers in my ListView.

Comment: thats the idea, every header gets a clone of his list. **so that clearing liste2 would not harm already-processed headers**

Comment: So is there a way of dynamically creating clones of lists? I have not found any.

Comment: :( sheesh.... `listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(g),liste2.clone());` though beware, that might not be a deepclone, but only a shallow one. But do test it out, perhaps you don't really need a deep clone after all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Shark I found the correct solution which was `listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(g),(List)liste2.clone());`.